# Resize a group of divs in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to resize this group of divs. How can I accomplish this?

```
function resizePanelsToBiggest(){
        //termPanel
        var maxheight = 0;

        var terms = $('.termPanel');

        for(var i = 0;i<terms.length;++i){

            terms[i].height = 500;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try just `$('.termPanel').height(500)` ?

Comment: Or even better, toggle a class name that will add additional CSS styles?

Comment: `terms[i].css('height','500');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the CSS based on an element that has a class so you could set it in the CSS file or style section or do this.

```
$('.termPanel').height(500);
```

The class selector grabs all of the element with that class and you set the stlye. No for loop needed.